# Nesting rows in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm nesting rows as per bootstrap's grid guidelines, however the second level of rows get the negative margin applied, thus resulting a horizontal scroll on the page. the first row is fine because of the container div which compensates for it, however according to bootstrap documentation I should not nest containers.

I could target the nested rows with css and remove the negative margin but not sure if I should be hacking the framework if there is work around?

Comment: share your code

Comment: You will need to provide the relevant code and bootstrap version so others can examine the code and determine how to fix it.

Comment: you could also put in code snippet or provide a CodePen link.